# Manage connection database with jdbc in jsf

Tags: jsf, jdbc, jakarta-ee, datasource

Hello please help me with this:

I need know as manage connection in jsf.
I use JSF 1.1 and use JDBC.

My project has a structure MVC.
My connection is gets from a Datasource.

Question 1:
Should I create in a package my connection factory class.
Question 2:
Where is correct managed commit and rolback in dao, businesslogig, backingbean package?
Question 4:
Where is correct managed open and close connection in dao, businesslogig, backingbean package?

My connection factory class is this below

```
public class ConexionDB {
private static Connection connection = null;
private static  DataSource dataSource=null;

private static void setupDataSource() throws IOException, NamingException {
    Propiedades propiedades = new Propiedades();
    Context  initialContext = new InitialContext();
    dataSource = (DataSource)initialContext.lookup(propiedades.getPropiedad("datasource.JNDI"));
}

public static Connection getConexion() throws SQLException, IOException, NamingException{
    if (dataSource== null)
        setupDataSource();
    return dataSource.getConnection();
}}
```

Besides it is advisable to close the connection at every access to data.
Or handle a single connection per action method managed bean to pass this parameter and make a single close.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Logically, you should manage transactions and connections at the top level of your services/stateless business logic objects. The commonly accepted approach for that is to rely on a dependency injection library to inject the connection/transaction handling aspect into the application. Take a look at Spring, specifically Spring JDBC.